# Series of operations on each group of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
from numpy import tile

group = np.repeat(['A','B'],10)
number = np.tile(range(0,10),2)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': group,
    'number' : number,
    'value' : np.random.rand(len(number))
})
```

and I want to create a new column where I perform a series of operations for each group, but I'm running into all sort of problems and my code is looking very clumsy.

The end goal is the following:

- For each group and number 0, df['New'] = 1, or any other constant number K
- For each group and number 1 to 9, df['New'] = df['New' - 1] * ( 1 - df['value' - 1] ), where the value is taken from the row above, which is what I mean by the "- 1" inside the brackets.
- For each group a new row is added, in this case corresponding to number 9 + 1 = 10, so that the operation above can be included as well.

So far what I've managed is the following:

```
df = df.set_index(['group', 'number'])

df['Constant'] = 1
df['New'] = df['Constant'] * (1 - df['value'])

def f(x):
    x.loc[('', 10), :] = ''
    return x

df = df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(f)

df['New'] = df.groupby('group').New.shift(1)
```

But here the shift operation is not working for me, and I still need to preserve the value of the constant in the first position for df['New'] instead of NaN from shifting.

Any pointers and ways to clean up this code are greatly appreaciated.

Edit: A simpler example would be like the following:
[image]

Comment: `For each group a new row is added, in this case corresponding to number 9 + 1 = 10, so that the operation above can be included as well.` what will the new row contains for all columns

Comment: The content of the other columns is not important. The only reason to create the new row would be to include the operation from the last row, which would otherwise disappear when doing the shifting.

Comment: Hi, your function does make the first part more compact, but I would still need to shift the columns down. 

For example, what I would like the new column to be would be like this:
* row(A , 0) = K
* row(A, 1) = K * ( 1 - value(A,0) )
* row(A, 10) = K * ( 1 - value(A,9) )

And then the same for group B

I hope this is a bit more clear? Thanks so far anyways!

Comment: what about tthe last row, you will get NaN value for it

Comment: Also can you explain this please `row(A , 0) = K * row(A, 1) = K * ( 1 - value(A,0) ) * row(A, 10) = K * ( 1 - value(A,9) )`

Comment: I added an example from Excel in the main post, hopefully that will clarify better what I'm trying to calculate

Comment: could you please provide explicit explanation, your ss does not clear what you are trying to do here, tell us what you want the as the result and the series of operation you want to apply

Comment: or is your formula wrong? should be D3*(1-C4). Can you post expected output for atleast 4-5 rows of your dataframe please

Comment: For each group (A and B) I want to create a new column. This column will start with a constant value, i.e., 1. This first row correspond to the columns with "number"=0. That is, the row where group = A or B, and number=0 will have the value of the constant, 1. The second row in column "new" will be: the value of "new" in the previous row, multiplied by (1 - the value of column "value" also from the previous row). Taking the output result from your example, for instance, the value of "new" in the second row, where group = A and number = 1, would be = 1 * ( 1-0.723864), and so on for all rows.

Comment: so the first row would have no value right?

Comment: The first row would have the value of the constant.

Comment: can you try my updated answer please and confirm if that's the result you wanted

Comment: still not. Thank you for trying, though!

Comment: hmm, can you post a data with 5 points and give us the expected output, cuz I did exactly what you specfied

Comment: I included a small example in the main post with 3 data points and the expected output.

Comment: Row 2 would be 1. Row 3 would be 1 * ( 1 - 0.5) = 0.5. Row 4 would be 0.5 * (1 - 0.4) = 0.3. Row 5 would be 0.3 * ( 1 - 0.3) = 0.21. I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: okay got it, updating answer

Comment: HEy I have updated my answer, could you please try it and let meknow if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the group, you can iterate through the rows in group and set the row value from previous rows.

In the below code, `i` is the index within each group and `group.iloc[i].name` gives you the index value corresponding to the original dataframe.

```
K = 1 # YOUR CONSTANT
df['new'] = K
def func(group):
    for i in range(1, len(group)):
        df.loc[group.iloc[i].name, 'new'] = df.iloc[group.iloc[i-1].name].new * (1 - group.iloc[i-1].value)
    
df.groupby('group').apply(func)
```

which gives us the expected output :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'number' : [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'value' : [0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0]
})

  group  number  value   new
0     A       0    0.5  1.00
1     A       1    0.4  0.50
2     A       2    0.3  0.30
3     A       3    0.0  0.21
```

Also for the below values of `group, number and new` the dataframe would be

```
   group  number     value       new
0      A       0  0.311951  1.000000
1      A       1  0.022941  0.688049
2      A       2  0.174398  0.672264
3      A       3  0.299853  0.555022
4      A       4  0.725469  0.388597
5      A       5  0.730307  0.106682
6      A       6  0.554905  0.028771
7      A       7  0.815290  0.012806
8      A       8  0.816718  0.002365
9      A       9  0.011935  0.000434
10     B       0  0.153680  1.000000
11     B       1  0.229228  0.846320
12     B       2  0.542225  0.652320
13     B       3  0.219170  0.298616
14     B       4  0.628088  0.233168
15     B       5  0.396675  0.086718
16     B       6  0.646968  0.052319
17     B       7  0.380830  0.018470
18     B       8  0.837341  0.011436
19     B       9  0.531990  0.001860
```

Comment: This is def solving most of the problem! However the addition of the extra row per group is still missing. In the first example you show here, that row with number = 3 wouldn't exist in the original df and needs to be added. So in the second example there would need to be added a 10th row for groups A and B. I'll mark it as the answer, tho, I already edited the dataframe manually so will keep this as a reference for future occasion when I try to solve it completely again. Thanks